# Error when launching server.js on Ethereum Hello World app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum

I followed this tutorial with the web3 1.0 source code.
The tutorial suggested to use web3 0.20.x but web3 0.20.x could not be installed in my computer(Ubuntu 16.04.3).

https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2

https://github.com/mjhm/hello_world_dapp

I installed and downloaded necessary files and ganache-cli is launched successfully.

```
Listening on localhost:8545
eth_accounts
eth_gasPrice
eth_sendTransaction

Transaction: 0xffcd7597522313760d262b251037024002054f66fa354892fe65955510f0049c
Contract created: 0x91885fa1a0644951b43ddb57d8d50c441fee26c6
Gas usage: 354524
Block Number: 1
Block Time: Tue Dec 26 2017 06:23:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getCode
```

Now I want to launch http_server with `npm run http_server` command but I got error:

```
> hello_world_voting@1.0.0 http_server /home/g-iot-info/hello_world_voting
> ./server.js

Unhandled rejection Error: Provider not set or invalid
```

How do I solve this problem?
I don't know where I should look at first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in setting the provider between version 0.20.0 and 1.0.0, so I don't think that's your problem. I was able to install and run their sample dApp, but `npm run http_server` didn't work for me either. Probably some environment setting I'm too lazy to figure out. Starting the app server with `npm start` instead worked fine. Maybe try that?

Comment: I should note that I used 1.0.0 for this as well and it worked (but I use 0.20.0 for my own development).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried `npm start` but it didn't work.